# Running Jasmine Unit Testing with Angular 2 from CDN running SystemJS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, jasmine

I am looking to run Angular 2 from CDN links with SystemJS and also want to setup unit testing with Jasmine.

I have managed to get it loading the application and setup Jasmine in my code which is shown below:

```js
/**
 * based on systemjs.config.js in angular.io
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {

  var addRouting = false;

  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var  map = {
    'app':                        'bundles/core/src', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@' + rxJsVersion,
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'https://npmcdn.com/angular2-in-memory-web-api', // get latest
    'ts':                         'https://npmcdn.com/plugin-typescript@' + typescriptPluginVersion + '/lib/plugin.js',
    'typescript':                 'https://npmcdn.com/typescript@' + typescriptVersion + '/lib/typescript.js'
  };

  //packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.ts',  defaultExtension: 'ts' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };

  var packageNames = [
      '@angular/common',
      '@angular/compiler',
      '@angular/core',
      '@angular/http',
      '@angular/platform-browser',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
      '@angular/testing',
      '@angular/upgrade',
      '@angular/forms',
  ]

  // add map entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/common@0.0.0-3'
  packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    map[pkgName] = 'https://npmcdn.com/' + pkgName + '@' + angularVersion;
  });

  // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });

  if ( addRouting ){
    // Router API
    map['@angular/router'] = 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/router@' + angularRouterVersion;
    packages['@angular/router'] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  var config = {
    transpiler: 'ts',
    typescriptOptions: {
        emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
        module: "commonjs",
        experimentalDecorators: true
    },
    meta: {
      'typescript': {
        "exports": "ts"
      }
    },
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }

  // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
  if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

This loads the Angular 2 library sucessfully and I am able to see Angular render in the page using the following markup:

```html
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/core/js/config.js') }}"></script>
     <script>

      function loadTestingScripts(){
       return Promise.all([
     System.import('bundles/core/src/app/app.spec.ts')
    ]);
      }

   Promise.all([
    System.import('app')
   ])
   .then( loadTestingScripts() )
   .then( window.onload )
   .catch( console.error.bind(console) );
     </script>
```

However when I try and run the following test code:

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing/index';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser/index';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core/index';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 

let comp:    AppComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
let el:      DebugElement;

describe('1st tests', () => {
  it('true is true', () => expect(true).toBe(true));
});

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AppComponent ], // declare the test component
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

  });
});
```

I receive an error 'TypeError: callback.apply is not a function' (zone.js@0.6.21:192).

However I have seen this achieved here with a beta version of the library:

http://embed.plnkr.co/vUjNLCVG8SVRYK6ZnKG0/

Is there any reason why the latest version cannot run unit testing with Angular 2 via a CDN url?

I am running Angular 2 final (2.0.0).

Below shows what I am trying to achieve:

https://embed.plnkr.co/7CCtow/

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be two parts to this question, so I'll call them out and answer them individually.

## Can we run jasmine unit testing with angular2 from CDN running systemjs?

**Yes. I've created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/w5kYI4?p=info) that seems to do what you wanted to do.**

At the time of this answer, the systemjs.config.js in this plunk has been pretty hacked to help illustrate the changes, but I've copied the important parts below in case I clean it up in the future. The main changes that I needed to make to go from an older RC to the "latest" angular2 release version (2.4 at the time of writing) was to resolve the testing dependencies from the CDN for:

- @angular/core/testing
- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing
- @angular/platform-browser/testing
- @angular/compiler/testing

And here's the appropriate fragment

```js
var map = {
    ...
    "@angular/core/testing": "https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core@2.4.0/bundles/core-testing.umd.js",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing": "https://npmcdn.com/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.4.0/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js",
    "@angular/platform-browser/testing": "https://npmcdn.com/@angular/platform-browser@2.4.0/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js",
    "@angular/compiler/testing": "https://npmcdn.com/@angular/compiler@2.4.0/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js",
   ...
};
```

**Note:** I am mapping the /testing dependencies to the umd format packages in the /bundles location. It looks like you're trying to map to the index.js inside @angular/core/testing/index which from what I can tell isn't the dependency that you're looking for, we want umd in this case.

## Is there any reason why the latest version cannot run unit testing with Angular 2 via a CDN url?

Regarding the second part of your question, It seems you may be referencing the latest zone.js dependency as opposed to angular2.

**No, there isn't a reason I can see.** With the right configuration it works perfectly well with the version I tested:

- 0.6.21
- 0.6.23
- 0.6.25 which was the latest 0.6.x (at the time of writing)

I did find that there were a lot of changes and a [few issues](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues) were raised in the [zone.js project](https://github.com/angular/zone.js) around this time, though many seem to be resolved by the versions we're talking about. the right configuration and order were important in my test running page where I have the fragment.

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.25?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/async-test.js?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/fake-async-test.js?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/sync-test.js?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/proxy.js?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/jasmine-patch.js?main=browser"></script>
```

Comment: For anyone interested here is an [angular4 version](https://plnkr.co/edit/X99HcO?p=info) of the angular2 plunk described above.